# Problems With KSoap2 into Activity Oncreate Event

Tags: java, android, soap, httpclient, ksoap

i have problems to use ksoap2 i cannot use SoapObjects i get an error :

ERROR :
Source Not Found

You can attacth the source by clicking Attacth Source Bellow
Button With label Atacth Source and After
public Abstract Class java.lang.classloader{..........}

***I WROTE Into my Activity Class***

SoapObject request = new SoapObject(nSpace, METHODNAME);

```
      SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
      envelope.dotNet=true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
      
      envelope.dotNet=true;
      envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

      HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
```

How do i can risolve this problem ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you hadn't send the envelop...

**`androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);`**

this is the only line not there in your code....

Comment: yea this line return a null value

Comment: when i call the method 
down vote
accept
you hadn't send the envelop...

androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope); i get this message ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1813 and a button with description Source Not Found